# Regex Match - outputing any matching chars in a file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to use the Regex.Match method to find matching characters in a file. At the moment the regex match method uses the line of the file in memory (strLine) and checks it against the specified (m_strRegEx) and any applicable options. Although how can I output from this just the mathching characters?

```
Match mtch;
if (m_bIgnoreCase == true)
    mtch = Regex.Match(strLine, m_strRegEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
else
    mtch = Regex.Match(strLine, m_strRegEx);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need the following:

```
Match mtch = Regex.Match(strLine, m_strRegEx, m_bIgnoreCase ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);
if (mtch.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mtch.Value);
}
```

or you can search strLine for all occurrences in one go:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(strLine, m_strRegEx, m_bIgnoreCase ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```